# Problems using IBrokers package

Tags: r, finance, ibrokers

I was trying to use IBrokers package with the simplest code like below:

```
library(IBrokers)

tws <- twsConnect()

aapl.csv <- file("AAPL.csv", open="wa")

# run an infinite-loop ( <C-c> to break )
reqMktData(tws, twsSTK("AAPL"), 
        eventWrapper=eWrapper.MktData.CSV(1), 
        file=aapl.csv)

close(aapl.csv)
close(tws)
```

I get this error:

```
2 1 321 Error validating request:-'oc' : 
cause - Incorrect generic tick list of 100,101,104,106,165,221,225,236. 
Legal ones for (STK)
```

And everything hangs...

the whole log is here:

```
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(IBrokers)
Loading required package: xts
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: 'zoo'

The following object(s) are masked from 'package:base':

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

IBrokers version 0.9-3:
Implementing API Version 9.64
This software comes with NO WARRANTY.  Not intended for production use!
See ?IBrokers for details
Warning messages:
1: package 'IBrokers' was built under R version 2.13.2
2: package 'xts' was built under R version 2.13.2
3: package 'zoo' was built under R version 2.13.2
>
> tws <- twsConnect()
>
> aapl.csv <- file("AAPL.csv", open="a")
>
> # run an infinite-loop ( <C-c> to break )
> reqMktData(tws, twsSTK("AAPL"),
+         eventWrapper=eWrapper.MktData.CSV(1),
+         file=aapl.csv)
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds2a
2 1 321 Error validating request:-'oc' : cause - Incorrect generic tick list of 100,101,104,106,165,221,225,236.  Legal ones for (STK) are: 100(Option Volume),101(Option Open Interest),104(Historical Volatility),105(Average Opt Volume),106(Option Implied Volatility),107(Close Implied Volatility),125(Bond analytic data),165(Misc. Stats),166(CScreen),225(Auction),233(RTVolume),236(inventory),258/47(Fundamentals),291(Close Implied Volatility),293(TradeCount),294(TradeRate),295(VolumeRate),318(LastRTHTrade),370(ParticipationMonitor),370(ParticipationMonitor),377(CttTickTag),377(CttTickTag),381(IB Rate),384(RfqTickRespTag),384(RfqTickRespTag),387(DMM),388(Issuer Fundamentals),391(IBWarrantImpVolCompeteTick),407(FuturesMargins),411(Real-Time Historical Volatility)

> (Command cancelled)
>
> close(aapl.csv)
> close(tws)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any idea for resolution or pointer to references highly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't seen this issue personally - and have the IBGateway running mostly 24/7.  According to the docs from IB http://individuals.interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide/tables/generic_tick_types.htm it seems valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that your tick list is bad. If you compare it to the valid ones it reports, you'll see that 221 is the culprit. Thankfully, doing `?reqMktData` tells us that you can specify your own tick list with the `tickGenerics` option. So just do something like

```
> reqMktData(tws, twsSTK("AAPL"), 
         eventWrapper=eWrapper.MktData.CSV(1), 
         file=aapl.csv, tickGenerics="100,101,104,106,165,225,236")
```

and you should be good to go.